QGIS 3.36-3.40 that same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
Does anyone know how to fix this? (chatGPT and other AIs recommend crap).
On QGIS 3.40 (as well as 3.36) start:
An error has occurred while executing Python code:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pupsik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\numpy\core_multiarray_umath.py", line 43, in getattr
sys.stderr.write(msg + tb_msg)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
Python version: 3.12.7 (main, Oct 25 2024, 11:18:09) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version: 3.40.0-Bratislava Bratislava, b56115d874
Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS34~1.0/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/pupsik/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/pupsik/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS34~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\grass\grass84\etc\python
C:\Users\pupsik\Documents
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.40.0\bin\python312.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\Lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.40.0\bin
C:\Users\pupsik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS34~1.0\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/pupsik/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python

ok, i've found the answer.
I just needed to delete packages (user installed packages) so those qgis those that QGIS uses by default are only left (and so don't coflict with each other):
Just delete these folders:
numpy, numpy.libs, numpy-2.1.3.dist-info
(somewhere here: C:\Users[YOUR USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\

Yes, you're using a version of numpy with this issue.
